# NMap Python for loop not running

Tags: python, nmap

I am working on a small tool that checks to see if any ports are open on a local machine.

However, the code only runs part way and stops before the first for loop. I get no errors and the rest of the program works correctly.

I have looked at some examples and some people have seemingly done this in the same way I have here, so I am really at a loss in understanding why this function does not work.

Please could someone help me understand why this is happening and how I could fix this?

Here is the function.

```
def nmapScan():
    global NetData
    nmScan = nmap.PortScanner()
    nmScan.scan(localIP, tgtPort)
    print  "check 1"
    for host in nmScan.all_hosts():
        hostInfo  = ('Host : %s (%s)' % (host, nmScan[host].hostname()))
        stateInfo = ('State : %s' % nmScan[host].state())
        print  "check 2"
        for protoCheck in nmScan[host].all_protocols():
            protoInfo = ('Protocol : %s' % protoCheck)
            lport = nmScan[host][protoCheck].keys()
            lport.sort()
            print  "check 3"
            for port in lport:
                print ('port : %s\tstate : %s' % (port, nmScan[host][protoCheck][port]['state']))
                NetData = hostInfo + stateInfo + protoInfo
                print  "check 4"
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: if program is stopping before first loop, so can you please print "nmScan.all_hosts()" before first loop to see if it actually have some values?

Comment: Yes printing nmScan.all_hosts() outputs my local ip